# Selection mode in JTable?

Tags: java, selectionmodel

I couldn't understand the difference between `multiple_selection_interval` and `single_interval_selection` in `JTable`.

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

next, is

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_SELECTION_INTERVAL);
```

What's the difference these?

Comment: What part of the API description for these values do you not understand? Why do you think we can explain it any better if we don't know what is confusing you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION` you can just select one row.
With `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` you can select more than one row, which are in one block. (e.g. you can select row 1 - 5, but not row 1-3 and row 4-6, therefor you need `ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`)